# Subquery returned more than 1 value, this is causing UPDATE statement to fail

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to update a column(PullFilesReady) in a table with 1 value if any of the `value` for a given `key` (i.e. 'blackbox','camera') in @JSON(I am storing JSON in a column) recordset is > 0. update code works for values when there is only one `key:value` > 0  but update code fails where there are multiple `key:value` > 0.

Ask::
I would like to have column PullFilesReady updated to 1 when either of the given key:value in @json is greater than 0. and if none of the value is >0 the set PullFilesReady to 0.

sample data in JSON format and also in Tables

```
select @json
>>>>
 {
    "blackbox": 1,
    "camera": 1,
    "config": 0,
    "events": 0,
    "isi_printf": 0,
    "kinematic": 0,
    "tool_table": 0
}

select * FROM OPENJSON(@JSON, '$') AS x where x.[Value] > 0

>>>>
key         value   type
blackbox    1       2
camera      1       2
```

Implementation

```
        UPDATE [HB].[Heartbeats] 
        SET [HB].[Heartbeats].[PullFilesReady] = (
            SELECT 
            CASE 
                WHEN 
                    [ResultSet].[Value] >0
                    THEN
                        1
                ELSE
                    0
            END
            FROM OPENJSON(@JSON, '$') AS ResultSet where ResultSet.[Value] > 0 
        )
        WHERE [HB].[Heartbeats].SystemName = @system
```

Error Message::

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 34 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery  follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: The error message is quite clear -- multiple values match in the subquery. You *can* eliminate the error using `select top (1)` or aggregation.  The right thing to do depends on your data and how you want to fix this problem, which you have not explained.

Comment: using `SELECT TOP(1) CASE ` helped in this regards. @GordonLinoff let me edit my post so that question is bit clear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have edited question, please can you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

You may try with the following statement using `EXISTS` and `OPENJSON()` (for parsing the JSON in the `RecordSet` column):

```
UPDATE [HB].[Heartbeats] 
SET [PullFilesReady] = CASE
   WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM OPENJSON([RecordSet], '$') 
      WHERE ([key] IN ('blackbox', 'camera')) AND ([value] > 0)
   ) THEN 1
   ELSE 0
END
WHERE [SystemName] = @system
```